# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar un solo valor de un DataSet?

Tags: r, dataset

Suponiendo tenemos este DataFrame como este:

[image: Data Set Ejemplo]

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el valor de la columna X en la fila "BA"?, se que puedo modificar toda la fila pero lo que quiero es ver como se hace ya que puede haber dataFrame de muchas columnas.

Comment: Si el texto "BA" es como pienso un "rowname", podrías hacer `df["BA", 1] <- valor`

Comment: Gracias, esa era la solucion.

Answer (score 3):

Supongamos un `data.frame` similar al de tu ejemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:5, 5),
                 y=sample(1:5, 5))

rownames(df) <- sample(LETTERS,5)
df

  x y
S 5 4
D 2 2
F 3 1
Y 4 5
X 1 3
```

Para acceder a cualquiera de las "celdas" de esta estructura puedes hacer uso de `[]` indicando filas y columnas, conociendo el índice de la fila:

```
df[2,1]
2
df[2,1] <- 0
df[2,1]
0
```

O bien, si el `data.frame` posee un `rowname` (no necesariamente lo tenga) puedes acceder usando éste:

```
df['D',1]
0
df['D',1] <- 2
df['D',1]
1
```